# Doctrine Many to Many join error

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to create a many to many join from the products to categories tables in ZF2 using Doctrine 2.

In my categories entity I have

```
/**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Products", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_to_category",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\joinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="category_id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\joinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id")}
     * )
     */
    private $products;
```

and in my products entity I have

```
/**
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Categories", mappedBy="products")
     */
    private $categories;
```

But i keep getting the error **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'The column category_id must be mapped to a field in class Application\Entity\Categories since it is referenced by a join column of another class.' in C:\Users\User\Documents\My Webs\freedomsnew\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php on line 328** when I try to lazy load the data.

I'm not sure what the error is trying to tell me and I cant see anything wrong!!

Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not posted the identity fields of both entities. The error suggests that the `Category` table doesn't have a column called `category_id` as it's PK. By default you should use `id` as the entity's ID (which would result in a column name of `id` on the db table); then update `referenceColumnName` to `id`.

Comment: Thank you @AlexP for your response, I just found the issue. category_id was spelt catagory_id on the database.  I also used "php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm validate-schema" to give more info on the error.